# `git clone` from command line leads to unexpected GitX SSH Remove Password dialog

Tags: git, gitx

In a terminal, when I try to

```
$ git clone <rep>
```

this happens

[image]

It's disturbing when you don't expect it.

Why does this happen, and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

`git` can use whatever is pointed to by the envariable `SSH_ASKPASS` (cf. [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)) as a helper when it needs a password, and something in GitX (specifically, [GitX-dev](https://rowanj.github.io/gitx/)) causes it to write this variable to use a tool internal to the GitX.app bundle.

To get rid of it in `bash`

```
unset SSH_ASKPASS
```